# Invalid entity supplied on getCollection

Tags: mysql, configuration, model

I made setted up a custom model but I'm stuck on getCollection methods which results in `Invalid entity supplied`

My setup:

IndexController.php

```
Mage::getModel('custom/customerobject')->getCollection();
// this is where the error happens
```

Resource/Customeobject/Collection.php

```
class Unreal_Custom_Model_Resource_Customerobject_Collection extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Resource initialization
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custom/customerobject');
    }

}
```

config.xml

```
  <models>
        <custom>
            <class>Unreal_Custom_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>unreal_resource</resourceModel>
        </custom>
        <unreal_resource>
            <class>Unreal_Custom_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <statusobject> 
                    <table>statusobject</table>
                </statusobject>
            </entities>
            <entities>
                <customerobject> 
                    <table>customerobject</table>
                </customerobject>
            </entities>
        </unreal_resource>
    </models>
```

sql script used to create table

```
if(!$installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($installer->getTable('custom/customerobject')))
{
    $customerObjectTable = $installer->getConnection()->newTable($installer->getTable('custom/customerobject'))
    ->addColumn('customer_id', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_INTEGER, null, array(
            'unsigned' => true,
            'nullable' => false,
            'primary' => true,
            'identity' => true,
            ), 'ID')
        ->addColumn('email', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
            'nullable' => false,
            ), 'Email')
        ->addColumn('password', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
            'nullable' => true,
            ), 'Password')
        ->addColumn('firstname', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
            'nullable' => false,
            ), 'FirstName')
                ->addColumn('lastname', Varien_Db_Ddl_Table::TYPE_TEXT, null, array(
            'nullable' => false,
            ), 'LastName');
    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($customerObjectTable);
}
```

Please help me out here because I have no idea where to start

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the Collection.php should extend from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract instead`of  `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as solution.